# Passing string causing crash sometimes in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I run into strange thing I'm getting a crash it this function:

```
func addQuestion(text:String!)
{
    if let txt=text
    {
        let question=PFObject(className: "questions")
        question["text"]=txt
        question["userAdding"]=PFUser.currentUser()
        question["answeredCount"]=0
        question.setObject([], forKey: "answers")
        question.setObject(NSDate(), forKey: "dateAdded")
        question.setObject(Int(arc4random()) % 10, forKey: "random")
        if debug
        {question.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)}
        else
        {question.saveEventually()}
    }

}
```

I'm getting a crash in "if let txt=text"
here is a back trace:

```
thread #1: tid = 0x241c0c, 0x00063470 pytajnik`pytajnik.ApiClient.addQuestion (text=Some, self=(ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}, debug = true))(Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.String>) -> () + 10796 at ApiClient.swift:32, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xe7ffdefe)
frame #0: 0x00063470 pytajnik`pytajnik.ApiClient.addQuestion (text=Some, self=(ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}, debug = true))(Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.String>) -> () + 10796 at ApiClient.swift:32
frame #1: 0x00035428 pytajnik`pytajnik.AddQuestionViewController.addQuestion (sender=AnyObject at 0x006ca054, self=0x17ef85d0)(Swift.AnyObject) -> () + 796 at AddQuestionViewController.swift:17
frame #2: 0x00035a6c pytajnik`@objc pytajnik.AddQuestionViewController.addQuestion (pytajnik.AddQuestionViewController)(Swift.AnyObject) -> () + 100 at AddQuestionViewController.swift:0
frame #3: 0x2a5fdc2a UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 70
frame #4: 0x2a5fdbd0 UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
...
```

The thing is, the app is not crashing always. Sometime it works sometime it doesn't. And I could't find a pattern.
Could somebody help me understand what is wrong?

UPDATE

```
thread #1: tid = 0x243f69, 0x0005d478 pytajnik`pytajnik.ApiClient.addQuestion (text=Some, self=(ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}, debug = true))(Swift.Optional<Swift.String>) -> () + 9820 at ApiClient.swift:35, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xe7ffdefe)
frame #0: 0x0005d478 pytajnik`pytajnik.ApiClient.addQuestion (text=Some, self=(ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}, debug = true))(Swift.Optional<Swift.String>) -> () + 9820 at ApiClient.swift:35
frame #1: 0x0002f80c pytajnik`pytajnik.AddQuestionViewController.addQuestion (sender=AnyObject at 0x006c4054, self=0x166a5560)(Swift.AnyObject) -> () + 1760 at AddQuestionViewController.swift:17
frame #2: 0x0002fe40 pytajnik`@objc pytajnik.AddQuestionViewController.addQuestion (pytajnik.AddQuestionViewController)(Swift.AnyObject) -> () + 100 at AddQuestionViewController.swift:0
frame #3: 0x2a5fdc2a UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 70
frame #4: 0x2a5fdbd0 UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
frame #5: 0x2a5e8862 UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 582
frame #6: 0x2a5fd63c UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 588
frame #7: 0x2a5fd316 UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 522
frame #8: 0x2a5f6be0 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 544
```

Comment: Careful with that "!".

Answer (score 0):

You declared the function parameter as implicitly unwrapped optional `!`, meaning you are sure it will never be `nil`.

If its possible that this parameter can be `nil` declare it as optional:

```
func addQuestion(text: String?) {
    if let txt = text {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: after changing ! to ? i have the same error but in line question["text"]=txt

Comment: Place breakpoints and step through your code. Examine the variables, espacially what happens to `quextion` and `txt`

Comment: I checked before and none of the variables is nil [link](http://s24.postimg.org/ly1wnh7t1/Screen_Shot_2014_11_06_at_11_04_01.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the `text` parameter as an implicitly unwrapped optional, which causes the app to crash if `text` is nil, and this is what's happening in your case.

Unless you have a specific reason to use an implicitly unwrapped optional, it's always better to use an optional `String?`, or a non optional `String` if the parameter can never be nil.

So to fix the problem just change your function signature to this:

```
func addQuestion(text:String?)
```

Suggested reading: [Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_504)

Comment: after changing ! to ? i have the same error but in line question["text"]=txt

Comment: It shouldn't, at least not because of `txt` - set a breakpoint on that and check if `question` is nil

Comment: I checked before and none of the variables is nil [link](http://s24.postimg.org/ly1wnh7t1/Screen_Shot_2014_11_06_at_11_04_01.png)

Comment: My opinion is that something is wrong with `PFObject`. Can you post the crash log in your question? (post it below the original question as an update, don't replace it)

Comment: Looked at that, but I am unable to figure out what's going on. As said, I think it's something related to `PFObject`, but I cannot help you more...